# how can i make a robe that follow leg movement without wasting too much memory on collision?

Tags: animation, rigging

so i made a character, and i have been rigging this for a while fixing many (calling it many would be an understatement at this point ...) problem that arise with it, and i just find it hard to control while this late in the game what i want to ask is how i can make this robe rig to follow the movement of the leg, and easier way to move the rig itself :)
[image]

to something like this

[image]

***Any suggestion, i.e would be really appreciated :D***

Comment: Can I suggest you try and give this question a more descriptive name? Something like "how do rig a skirt to follow leg movements?" or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Copy Rotation Constraints. Place them on the bone chains of the skirt bones and make them follow the leg bones, adjusting their influence based on how closely you want the skirt to follow the movement.

For extra control, you could create one set of skirt bones to auto-follow the legs and make them the parent of an additional bone for manual control.

[image]

The included .blend only has two bone chains for the coat, and they were done with automated weights, but it should guide you right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!, now to the complimentary question to make this answer complete is how can i make the rig easier, ex : how can i make a widget that can control 2 bones, or easier way to control many rig that doesn't hinder the rig movement dynamism itself

Comment: This is where things can get more complex, and there are several ways to approach this. Using the example before,  you could use an additional non-deformation bone and have the MCH bones point at that instead of the legs. Think of it as master bone control bone. I would also suggest looking up Humane Rigging in YouTube. Its old but still *very* relevant.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @Vectorius i'm going to check on that very soon :D